# How could I make this studio setup work?

Tags: speakers, setup, studio

I'm fairly new to this and I hope this is the right place to ask. I apologise if it's not.

Let's say I have the following speakers/subwoofer:

http://microlab.com/en/catalog/2.1/wired/m-200-platinum/

I also have a pair of these studio monitors:

http://www.m-audio.com/products/view/bx5-d2

Now, I want to buy a external audio interface (most likely this: http://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i2 or something very similar) and still use my pair of studio monitors (bx5-d2) and **only** the subwoofer from the speaker/sub system (microlab m-200).

How do I connect the studio monitors and the subwoofer to the audio interface outputs (L and R outputs)? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't waste the effort.

1. the M-Audios are internally bi-amped & need a line level signal.
2. The Microlab needs a stereo line level feed which it then amplifies to send to the satellites... far too much signal for the M-Audio.
3. There's little chance that adding that cheapo sub to the M-Audio system will improve the sound quality. In all likelihood it will reduce it. You will have no control over the crossover frequency or sub levels. Those tiny PC speaker subs are usually abysmal & over-emphasise at 125Hz or so, which will help nothing.

Leave the cheap 2.1 system where it belongs, on a gaming PC, playing WoW ;)